# 'Document constructed by $facet exceeds the limit' with allowDiskUse:true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, facet

I am currently using mongoDb v4.4 with Mongoose v5.10. And getting the limit exceed error by $facet in my Aggregation query which is providing very large number of responses with the `allowDiskUse: true` option.

```
MongoError: document constructed by $facet is 104859602 bytes, which exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes
```

It was working fine till I was on mongoDb v3.4 with Mongoose v4.13 for large results.

After making aggregate pipeline with facets and using `aggregate.allowDiskUse(true)`,  mongo query logs does show the query with allowDiskUse flag being true but still getting error.

Comment: I had same query so this answer helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70451202/11646798

Answer (score 1):

Because this `$facet` stage exceeds 16 megabyte BSON document size limit.

Refer to [$facet consideration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#considerations):

> The output of the $facet stage is subject to the 16 megabyte BSON Document Size limit. If the results of the $facet stage exceed the BSON Document Size limit, the aggregation produces an error.

---

In your case, maybe this configuration command will help

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes: BIGGER_THAN_100MB })
```

Comment: But the error is regarding the 100MB limit, so is it implied from that?
"document constructed by $facet is 104859602 bytes, which exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes"

Comment: No, the error is regarding **document size**, as it says 'Document constructed by...'.
It should be implied as:
'document constructed by $facet is 104859602 bytes, which exceeds the limit of 16*1024*1024 bytes'

Comment: I have update the question which actual error that is coming. Can you look at that
It's showing the 100MB limit

Comment: It seems `$facet` stage cannot use disk, according to [mongodb documnetation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#memory-restrictions). Could you provide log message, as instructed: 
> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, the profiler log messages and diagnostic log messages includes a usedDisk indicator if any aggregation stage wrote data to temporary files due to memory restrictions.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-40317
can you check this.
is the allowDiskUse not of use anymore for facets?

Comment: I just come into another question related to your issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445248/how-to-bypass-facet-memory-100mb-memory-limit-on-each-of-its-pipeline-in-mongod . I also edited my answer

Comment: Actually, that's what me and my friend Ayush (working with me) came upon a solution, but there we posted concern about the RAM being used instead of disk usage.

Comment: We had used the "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes" mongo server paramter for increasing the default RAM usage for facet query operation