# How to bypass $facet memory 100MB memory limit on each of its pipeline in MongoDB V4.4?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I was working with MongoDB 3.4 and recently upgraded it to 4.4 on Beta environment. I have a query using facet which is giving 100MB size limit exceeded issue.I saw Jira link explaining this issue here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-40317

The query is dynamically made based on user input so its hard to make changes on query directly I am thinking of it as last resort.

I am looking for anyway to bypass this limit. AllowDiskUsage also doesn't work as stated in above link.

Comment: Maybe show us your query, some sample input data and expected result. Otherwise it will be difficult to give any answer.

Comment: My bad this is the link to the query trust me no one would wanna see this: https://pastebin.com/K4DKvCWA

Comment: Also I saw this feedback 
https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924280-database/suggestions/40081492-allow-configuration-of-100mb-memory-limit-per-aggr
Asya talks about some internal parameter? which parameter is she talking about?

Comment: check if this can help also for $facet: db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: 335544320})
With the above command RAM limit changed from default 100MB to 320 MB

Comment: And you can check the value with: use admin
db.runCommand( { getParameter : 1, “internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes” : 1 } )

Comment: Thank you pointed me in the right direction db.adminCommand({ setParameter: 1, internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 335544320}) this thing fixes my issue.

@R2D2 Can you share this in answer?

Comment: @AyushBahuguna: Thanks for sharing  the exact parameter !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed this can fix the issue:

```
  db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 335544320})
```

With the above command affected RAM limit changed from default 100MB to 320 MB

to see if the change is in place:

```
 use admin
 db.runCommand( { getParameter : 1, “internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes” : 1 } )
```

This change is temporary , to make it permanent you will need to add to the mongodb.conf file to take effect on startup:

```
 setParameter:
     internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 335544320
```

Comment: Hi @R2D2  just one last thing, since for mongodb 3.4 we were using allowDiskUsage for increasing this $facet limit which means additional memory will be taken by disk storage(temporary file ) but now with mongodb 4.4 and changing this setting will it consume RAM?

Comment: this ram allocation is expected to be part of the allocated cacheSizeGB ( if not specified by default allocating to ~50% of host RAM )

Comment: btw , there is one more parameter that may affect you : internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes  also defaulting to 100MB

Comment: Thanks will look into it, I just want this command to use disk space instead of ram I think I should try virtual memory. Is there someway I can have it consume more disk space other than RAM?

Comment: You may add swap but this will significantly decrease execution times ...

Answer (score 1):

Not fully related to your problem, but your aggregation pipeline looks a bit silly. Why on earth do you use all these `$and` / `$or` with just one argument?

If I am not mistaken, then your aggregation pipeline looks like this:

```
responses.aggregate([
   {
      '$match': {
         surId: '5f548bda279ef41b7a9cd23c',
         preview: 0,
         resStatus: '1',
         archive: { '$exists': false },
         modified: {
            '$gte': ISODate('2020-08-31T20:59:59.999Z'),
            '$lt': ISODate('2020-11-30T21:00:00.000Z')
         },
         'resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141': { $in: [Object] }
      }
   },
   { $project: { 'resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141': 1, surId: 1 },
   {
      '$facet': {
         '0': [
            { '$match': { 'resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141': { '$elemMatch': [Object] } } },
            { '$addFields': { 'resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141': { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'item', cond: { '$and': [Array] } } } } },
            {
               '$project': {
                  surId: '$surId',
                  d_DMID7235_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  d_DMID7237_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  d_DMID7239_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  d_DMID7240_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  d_DMID7241_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  d_DMID7242_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  d_DMID7243_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  d_DMID7244_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  d_DMID7245_0_d: { '$filter': { input: '$resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141', as: 'dmi_0', cond: { '$eq': [Array] } } },
                  index: '0'
               }
            },
            {
               '$project': {
                  surId: '$surId',
                  DMID7235: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7235_0_d', 0] },
                  DMID7237: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7237_0_d', 0] },
                  DMID7239: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7239_0_d', 0] },
                  DMID7240: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7240_0_d', 0] },
                  DMID7241: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7241_0_d', 0] },
                  DMID7242: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7242_0_d', 0] },
                  DMID7243: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7243_0_d', 0] },
                  DMID7244: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7244_0_d', 0] },
                  DMID7245: { '$ifNull': ['$d_DMID7245_0_d', 0] },
                  index: '0'
               }
            }
         ],
         '1': ['... same as above'],
         '2': ['... same as above'],
         '3': ['... same as above'],
         '4': ['... same as above'],
         '5': ['... same as above'],
         '6': ['... same as above'],
         '7': ['... same as above'],
         total: [{ '$count': 'total' }],
         baseValue: ['... same as above']
      }
   },
   { '$project': { mergedArray: { '$concatArrays': ['$0', '$1', '$2', '$3', '$4', '$5', '$6', '$7', '$total', '$baseValue'] } } },
   { '$unwind': '$mergedArray' },
   { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: '$mergedArray' } }
])
```

All your operations are based on one single field `resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141`, this looks strange. Maybe pure javascript code solves it better.

You may use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/). Actually I don't see the reason to use `$facet` at all.

Without sample input data and sample result it's difficult to give an answer, but I would assume the aggregation pipeline could be written much simpler.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the post can't imagine the effort, secondly these additional $or & $and are placed as parent and it may or may not have more child. Like I have seen 1 parent $or and then child $or and then some stuff but it is also possible to have 1 parent $or with more stuff (I don't know if this makes sense). The only static thing about this query is allowdiskuse. Btw your suggestion is great for using javascript, changing mongo config solution is fine for me but not good on prod servers so I will try to use javascript more for this.Also the no. of fields are also dynamic.

Comment: I wish I could share the input and output as well but sad part is that this is a helper function for the api in use :) and I don't know where I can put all the input and output to explain the situation maybe github .md file?.

Comment: Maybe pay attention the the second stage I added `{ $project: { 'resAObj.601aaf29fd93f74cab932141': 1, surId: 1 }` - looks like these are the only fields which are used further down, so you can remove all other fields. This makes the facet much smaller, I guess.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, will add a projection in between there, this should downsize all the documents, Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use mongoose utils allowdiskusage like this:

```
return OrderEntity
        .aggregate(compendiumAggregation(query))
        .allowDiskUse(true)
        .then(success(res))
        .catch(next);
```