# MongoDb error: 'document constructed by $facet is [104858087] bytes, which exceeds the limit of [104857600]‘

Tags: mongodb

I’m encountering this error with MongoDb: 'document constructed by $facet is [104858087] bytes, which exceeds the limit of [104857600]‘ even though I already have allowDiskUse.
I’m certain that there is no syntax error with allowDiskUse since we have it working with our test db. When it comes to a much bigger db, the error comes up.
Do you have any idea of the cause for this error?
Thank you in advance!

I tried allowDiskUse and google for the same error.

Comment: have you read the documentation?

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#considerations 

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#std-label-agg-pipeline-limits

Comment: Can you share the actual code? It doesn't look like `allowDiskUse` is working (it doesn't work for all aggregation stages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase this internal limit threshold via:

```
use admin
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 335544320})
```

(the example change the limit from 100MB to 320MB )

You can check the changed values via:

```
db.runCommand( { getParameter : 1, “internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes” : 1 } )
```

check also: internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes

as we have concluded already in more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445248/how-to-bypass-facet-memory-100mb-memory-limit-on-each-of-its-pipeline-in-mongod)

but in general there maybe option to avoid $facet at all ...

default values for tresholds if you need to set them back:

```
 "serverParameters": {
"internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": 104857600,
"internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": 104857600,
"internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": 104857600,
"internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
"internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": 104857600,
"internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": 0,
"internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": 104857600,
"internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600
}
```

You can get all available params/values via:

```
db.adminCommand({getParameter:"*"});
```

P.S.
As explained in the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#considerations)

As each stage in a $facet executes, the resulting document is limited to 100 megabytes. Note the allowDiskUse flag doesn't affect the 100 megabyte size limit, since $facet can't spill to disk.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try that. But can you pls explain why I still have the error with allowDiskUse?

Comment: allowDiskUse has no relations to the limits you face in  $facet , added to the answer some more details  and link to the docs where it is explained

Comment: Thank you so much! It’s the first time I work with mongodb so a lot of new things I don’t understand

Comment: MongoDB is great and community behind  too!   It  you like my answer please accept and give some cudos ... ;)