# Aggregate query with $facets on large data requires optimisation in mongoDB4.4

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, query-optimization, facet

In mongo3.4, working but with large execution time with help of `allowDiskUse: true`.

Getting below error in mongoDb 4.4 as `allowDiskUse` flag has been deprecated for `$facets` after mongo3.6

```
MongoError: document constructed by $facet is 104859602 bytes, which exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes
```

Any suggestions on how to optimise the query as with tens of thousands of responses, there becomes timeout issue and the $facet document size limit.

Link for typical query -> https://pastebin.com/K4DKvCWA
(where number of facets is some queries are more than 50-60)
This is how a typical response is looking.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("61bb0cbaadcb1d5e110b2f19"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-12-16T09:54:59.052Z"),
"surId" : ObjectId("61b9cc87c22bc6349257862f"),
"resPObj" : {
    "61b9cc87c22bc63492578630" : {
        "prevQId" : null,
        "prevPId" : null
    }
},
"resAObj" : {
    "61b9ccf591942e3471e8eb98" : [
        {
            "colId" : "61b9ccf591942e3471e8eb99",
            "rowId" : "61b9ccf591942e3471e8eb9e"
        }
    ],
    "61b9cd0413bb87346ba0f444" : [
        {
            "isNa" : 0,
            "text" : "url with edata",
            "rowId" : "61b9cd0413bb87346ba0f446"
        }
    ],
    "61b9cd60005cbf3499a6e628" : [
        {
            "colId" : "61b9cd60005cbf3499a6e62a",
            "rowId" : "61b9cd60005cbf3499a6e62e"
        },
        {
            "colId" : "61b9cd60005cbf3499a6e62a",
            "rowId" : "61b9cd60005cbf3499a6e62d"
        }
    ],
    "61b9ccac75518e34b8358947" : [
        {
            "rowText" : "",
            "rowId" : "61b9ccac75518e34b835894a"
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: which query? on which data? what is the expected output? in general instead of `facet` many times `$group` can be used

Comment: for anyone interested in this issue, there are several discussions related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70432085/document-constructed-by-facet-exceeds-the-limit-with-allowdiskusetrue and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445248/how-to-bypass-facet-memory-100mb-memory-limit-on-each-of-its-pipeline-in-mongod. I tried to help, but it seems not work as Loki expected

Comment: @Takis_. Sorry for the delay. 
I've updated the question with query link and response collection document example.